# Why can't this IF-STATEMENT work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

```
INSERT INTO individual_key_log (stuff, stuff1, stuff2) 

VALUES("YOUR_PK_NAME_HERE", 2, 3)

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stuff="YOUR_PK_NAME_HERE",

    IF (1 > 0) THEN
        SET stuff1 = 1;
    ELSE
        SET stuff1 = 2;
    END IF;
```

How can I achieve the above logic? I'm using MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [`IF` syntax in manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if). Your syntax is wrong. You can try this:

```sql
INSERT INTO individual_key_log (stuff, stuff1, stuff2) 
VALUES("YOUR_PK_NAME_HERE", 2, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stuff="YOUR_PK_NAME_HERE", stuff1 = IF(1 > 0, 1, 2)
```

**Update**

If you want not to update value and leave it as is, use this query.

```sql
INSERT INTO individual_key_log (stuff, stuff1, stuff2) 
VALUES("YOUR_PK_NAME_HERE", 2, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stuff1 = IF(X > 0, VALUES(stuff1), stuff1)
```

If condition inside `IF` is true, `stuff1` will be updated with new value from `INSERT`. And it will be untouched otherwise.

Comment: Can I have a parent IF that basically says IF (X >0) THEN execute all the assignments, otherwise, don't do anything?

Comment: No, you must write `IF` for each column. Of course, condition in `IF` can be the same. But it cannot be extracted for use only once. See also new example in answer about "don't do anything".